# Can't render math with Docusaurus

Tags: javascript, docusaurus, katex

I can't get math equations getting rendered by using KaTex in my markdown files and don't know why. Can anyone help me, please?

I tried to reproduce it by creating a new clean [Docusaurus project](https://github.com/achimstruve/docusaurus_math_minimal) and afterwards followed the exact instructions on  [how to include KaTex math](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/math-equations).

In this clean project I created an example page under ./src/pages/markdown-math-page.mdx.

```
---
title: Markdown page example
---

# Markdown page math example

Test math:
$a
$a + b = c$
```

It renders as shown in the image below, but the math equations aren't rendered as they should.
What step am I missing?

[image: Screenshot of the rendered markdown-math-page.mdx page]

I tried to reproduce the problem by following all outlined steps in the tutorial. Also there are no error or warning messages once I compile the page. The math just doesn't get rendered as it should.

Answer (score 2):

To enable KaTex, you need to follow the instructions under the `Configuration` section: [how to configure KaTex math](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/math-equations#configuration)

1. Install the necessary packages using either npm, yarn, or pnpm
2. Modify `docusaurus.config.js` file (import plugins, add them to preset options, and include KaTex stylesheet)

Result:

```
---
title: Markdown page example
---

# Markdown page math example

Test math:

Let $f\colon[a,b]\to\R$ be Riemann integrable. Let $F\colon[a,b]\to\R$ be
$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t)\,dt$. Then $F$ is continuous, and at all $x$ such that
$f$ is continuous at $x$, $F$ is differentiable at $x$ with $F'(x)=f(x)$.
```

[image]